# Large shiny-server docker image size

Tags: r, docker, shiny, dockerfile

I am currently dockerizing a mixture of R notebooks and shiny dashboards that will get served in a shiny server. As can be noted from the Dockerfile, I am starting from a `rocker/shiny` image and go through the following build steps:

1. Install required packages from a `renv.lock` file
2. Execute `main.R` that will take care of rendering the .Rmd files and put the .html outputs in a `/reports` folder.
3. Copy both the knitted documents and shiny dashboards in the `shiny-server` folder for servin.
4. Copy shiny server configuration file
5. Remove temporary files (working directory and downlaoded packages).
6. Expose `8080` port.

Now, the resulting image built this way weighs ~1.79GB which sounds way above what I was expecting (the base [`rocker/shiny`](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny/tags) image is just ~400mb).
I am wondering what I am missing (too much layer duplication perhaps?) or what's wrong with the `Dockerfile`.

Project folder structure:

```
.
├── cool-report.Rproj
├── Dockerfile
├── R
│   └── main.R
├── readme.md
├── renv
│   ├── activate.R
│   ├── library
│   ├── settings.dcf
│   └── staging
├── renv.lock
├── rmarkdown
│   ├── area1.Rmd
│   ├── area2.Rmd
│   └── data
│       ├── data_import_1.R
│       └── data_import_2.R
├── shiny
│   └── mtcars_example
│       └── app.R
└── shiny-server.conf
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

COPY . /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp

RUN echo "options(renv.consent=TRUE)" >> .Rprofile

# Install packages from renv
RUN R -e "install.packages('remotes', repos = c(CRAN = 'https://cloud.r-project.org'))" \
  && R -e "remotes::install_github('rstudio/renv')" \
  && R -e "renv::restore(confirm = FALSE)"

# Render report(s)
RUN Rscript ./R/main.R

# Copy reports and shiny dashboards
RUN cp -r ./reports /srv/shiny-server/reports \
  && cp -r shiny/* /srv/shiny-server/reports

WORKDIR /

# Copy config files and server executable
COPY shiny-server.conf /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf

# Cleanup temp files
RUN rm -rf /tmp/*

# Expose port as on shiny-server.conf
EXPOSE 8080
```

`docker image history -H <image-id>` output:

```
andodet@t480s:~/code/study/cool-report$ docker image history -H d21975ad912d
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
d21975ad912d        About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 8080                  0B
11345fbe7c72        About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c rm -rf /tmp/*                        0B
ce8b33984b85        About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:1d2d0c462c909cc4…   741B
761bc2a982cd        About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /                     0B
5aa2ae037138        About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c cp -r ./reports /srv/shiny-server…   1.76MB
12b3a3505ae9        About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c Rscript ./R/main.R                   1.76MB
69cacc1ad08d        About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c R -e "install.packages('remotes',…   328MB
eb07c8335c8f        2 hours ago         /bin/sh -c echo "options(renv.consent=TRUE)"…   53B
55a14476302f        2 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /tmp                  0B
84e502e37546        2 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:dfcc724126bc931ba…   31.3MB
f40ad3a5dadd        5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-serv…   0B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:fef7b189480bb622…   359B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 3838                  0B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c wget --no-verbose https://downloa…   513MB
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   313MB
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["R"]                    0B
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c apt-get update   && apt-get insta…   506MB
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV R_VERSION=3.6.1 LC_AL…   0B
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV BUILD_DATE=2019-12-12    0B
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG BUILD_DATE               0B
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG R_VERSION                0B
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL org.label-schema.li…   0B
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:8f7dc710e276f54a3…   101MB
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but the sizes shown on Docker Hub are compressed sizes. If you run `docker images rocker/shiny:latest` locally, you'll see that the `rocker/shiny` image is actually 1.43GB uncompressed. Most of that comes from those `wget`/`apt-get` steps in the bottom half of the image history output.

Comment: That makes perfect sense @gregL, I will rebuild the image including the `--compress` flag and see what'll come out.

Comment: hi @anddt, Did you find any way to reduce the shiny image size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting files with `rm -rf` does not free up any space. Docker images are made out of additive layers, a bit like commits in Git history—the old layers will always still be there.

You can try multi-stage builds, or you can switch all those RUNs into a single run that calls a shell script which then deletes the files at the end of the shell script. Since the layer is only created at the end of the RUN, if temporary files are gone by the time the RUN is over they won't use up any space.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've moved the first 4 `RUN` commands to a small [shell script](https://gist.github.com/andodet/c9f4c37cdf6624349394ef985c369fb9) and surprisingly it didn't make the image size any smaller despite fewer `RUN` calls.

Comment: You also need to delete any unwanted files as part of that shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Some recommendations to gain a smaller Docker image containing a shiny app (with or without Shiny Server):

- Use another base image than `rocker/shiny` that ships with [loads of packages](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2), for example [`rocker/r-base`](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-base) and install only those R packages which are actually used. A glimple on both base images shows the magnitude of size difference:

```
rocker/shiny    latest         1aecb46da7ee   2 weeks ago         1.47GB
rocker/r-base   latest         ce611fb80498   3 months ago        838MB
```

- It could be helpful to go one step farther and adjust the [rocker Dockerfiles themselves](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker) to build a custom rocker image that contains only really necessary parts (or build a completely new image from scratch).
- If Alpine Linux is an option, [rhub offers minimal Docker images for R](https://hub.docker.com/r/rhub/r-minimal)
- Use a [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file to ensure only needed files end up in the image (and, nice side effect, speeds up the build process)
- Consider using a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/)

More and other approaches are welcome :)